# use web browser control in feed rss reader

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I followed this guide to create a rss reader

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487167(v=vs.92).aspx

but I would like to use web browser control to open the feed instead of the WebBrowserTask. How can I achieve it?

Note: I am using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent auto refreshing try this in your `webBrowser.xaml.cs`

```
    String _oldUrl;
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
         String url = NavigationContext.QueryString["url"];
         if(url!=_oldUrl)
         {
              if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
              {
                     browser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
              }
              _oldUrl = url;
         }
    }
```

Comment: not work,the page continues to auto refresh when I turn off the screen

Comment: made a mistake, just corrected it. It should work now. Else, please paste your code here for me to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to your link. You may follow the following approach:

Create a webBrowser control on your page. Call it say `"webBrowser"`

Use `webBrowser.Navigate(uri);` instead of the below three statements

```
        WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
        webBrowserTask.Uri = uri;
        webBrowserTask.Show();
```

in the function `feedListBox_SelectionChanged`. Hope it helps.

Comment: it works, but I would like to open the web browser control in new PhoneApplicationPage

Comment: Add the webBrowser control to the new page. And send the uri to that page as a query parameter. Then on the new page in the OnNavigatedTo function extract the query string as `url` and then do this `webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));` If you are not able to proceed let me know.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still a beginner, how do you send the uri To That page as a query parameter?

Comment: on the mainpage navigate to page two using `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Page2.xaml?Url=<your url>",UriKind.Relative));` and on the Page2.xaml override the onNavigatedTo function and extract the query string using `String Url= this.NavigationContext.QueryString["Url"];` then you may use the above statement of `webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));`

Comment: i have using String Url= this.NavigationContext.QueryString["Url"]; in page2.cs and webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url)); but i have error because "navigate" and "Url" does not exist in current context

Comment: you have to create page2 as Page2.xaml page and not Page2.cs. When you create it as Page2.xaml, write that code in Page2.xaml.cs. WebBrowser control wont be accessible on Page2.cs but you will be able to create a webBrowser control on Page2.xaml and reference it in the code behind

Comment: i have create page2.xaml.cs wacth my screenshot http://img600.imageshack.us/img600/4668/webg.png (webbrowser is page2),Thanks for your patience

Comment: Please read the other answer which I have posted as I could not format it here for your understanding. Don't write code in the constructor which I can see you have done in your screenshot. Let it contain only InitializeComponent() statement.

Answer (score 0):

call the webBrowser.xaml page like this

`NavigationSerivce.Navigate(new Uri("<webBrowser.xaml path>?url="+url,UriKind.Relative));`

on the webBrowser.xaml

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" >
             <phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="browser" />
        </Grid>
```

and on the webBrowser.xaml.cs do:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        String url = NavigationContext.QueryString["url"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            browser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
```

please Check for compilation errors. It should work

Comment: thanks, it works but when I turn off the screen the web browser control auto refresh,how i can fix it?

Comment: added another answer to prevent auto refreshing ;)